# How to set values in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I thought I understood how for loops and arrays worked but for some reason when I try to use them together I'm not getting what I expected. Basically I want to create a for loop to increment the the index of the array and assign each element in the array  the number entered from the user. In C++ it would look something like this:

```
int array[11];

for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
  array[i]=valueEntered;
}
```

Now I'm trying to recreate this in Visual Basic. This is what I have:

```
Dim gasArray(11) As Decimal

        For i As Integer = 0 To 11 Step 1
            gasArray(i) = Val(priceTB.Text)

            priceLB.Items.Add(Val(priceTB.Text))
            priceTB.Clear()
        Next
```

but my price list box (priceLB) prints out only the first number entered and 0's for the rest of the array. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Simple fix using a global counting variable outside of sub.

```
Dim gasArray(11) As Decimal

        gasArray(i) = Val(priceTB.Text)
        i += 1
        priceLB.Items.Add(Val(priceTB.Text))
        priceTB.Clear()


        If i > 11 Then
            enterBtn.Enabled = False
            priceTB.Enabled = False
        End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you call `priceTB.Clear()`? I think this will clear the text box, and hence the rest of the array becomes 0.

Comment: I need to clear the text box so that you can input the next number. IE: element 2, 3, 4, etc

Comment: Then it is not the correct way to code, as the loop will be executed 12 times before you input the next number. Why don't you put the it inside the Click event (of a button to Add) and don't use loop, but keep track of the index to assign to the array in a variable?

Comment: Don't know why I was forcing myself to use a for loop. Lack of sleep maybe. Created a global variable counter to control the number entered. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

While reading your case, I understood that you need to add 10 different numbers in an array from a single text box. Ok as @rcs said `priceTB.Clear()` will empty the text box after the first iteration.

So i recommend you to use [inputbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in your case. It will help you to get 10 different values in 10 iterations of that loop.

```
Dim gasArray(9) As Decimal

For i As Integer = 0 To gasArray.length - 1          
  gasArray(i) = Val(InputBox("Enter a value", "Hello", String.Empty))
  priceLB.Items.Add(gasArray(i))
Next
```